# Setting up SBT to resolve the dependencies offline

Tags: jenkins, sbt

I am trying to setup `Jenkins` on a UNIX VM. It is devoid of internet access. The intended jobs are `SBT` projects which would require `dependencies`(cache) in the `/var/lib/jenkins/.ivy2` folder. How can I set it up? Is there a way I could download dependencies from somewhere else and copy it into the offline machine?

Comment: You should be able to run the same build on another machine, and then copy the `.ivy2` folder, like you mention.

Comment: It's done. I copied .ivy2 from the windows machine where i could download dependencies from the online repositories. Thanks @ChristopherOrr